# Counting number of fields in a document

Tags: php, mongodb

```
{ "_id": "apples", "qty": 5 }
{ "_id": "bananas", "qty": 7, "price": 12.00 }
{ "_id": "avocados", "qty": 14, "price": 14.00, "status:" "available" }
```

How do I get the `count` of fields in a document? So in the above example, the counts would be `2`, `3` and `4` respectively.

Comment: where is your `count` field ?

Comment: Not looking to get a specific field, I just need the number of fields present in document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use json_decode to decode your document and then count number of fields :

```
$document = '{ "_id": "apples", "qty": 5 }';
$count    = count((array) json_decode($document));
```

Comment: Not individually ofcourse, thats easy. I need to run a find query and instead of the objects returned, I just need the count of fields. But I believe the only way is to get each document and then run count.

Answer (score 0):

The *count()* function do the work !

```
count($myDocument);
```